# CSS - Center several texts

Tags: css

I am looking a way to center my texts.

I just have a problem with my texts for now. How to align correctly my texts please? The solution exists sur stackoverflow but I don't get the desired result.

I would  like to use a simple way beacause I am a beginner.

Here is my codes below, I hope my code is correct overall.

Thank you very much for your help.

```css
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.image-wrapper{
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 90%;
}

/* All of these styles are shared by the .img element */

.img {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 197px;
  width: 90%;
}

.img.img-01 {
  background-image: url("https://zupimages.net/up/19/51/vn88.jpg");
}

.img.img-02 {
  background-image: url("https://zupimages.net/up/19/51/9fik.jpg");
}

.img.img-03 {
  background-image: url("https://zupimages.net/up/19/51/dwq9.jpg");
}

.img-title{
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    color: #cd2122;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: left;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: Open Sans;
}

.img-text{
   font-family: Open Sans;
   font-size: 13px;
   line-height: 19px;
   color: #535353;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   margin-left: 20px;
   float: left;
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="image-wrapper">
          <img class="img-01 img">
          <div class="img-title">Trust Management</div>
          <div class="img-text">Assets trust management represents one of the             most popular operation methods in the world stock markets for                   companies as well as individuals. Among the advantages of assets trust           management we may mention many.</div>
        </div>
       <div class="image-wrapper">
         <img class="img-02 img">
         <div class="img-title">Well Documented</div>
          <div class="img-text">Assets trust management represents one of the             most popular operation methods in the world stock markets for                   companies as well as individuals. Among the advantages of assets trust           management we may mention many.</div>
       </div>
      <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img class="img-03 img">
        <div class="img-title">Great Support</div>
         <div class="img-text">Assets trust management represents one of the             most popular operation methods in the world stock markets for                   companies as well as individuals. Among the advantages of assets trust           management we may mention many.</div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: can you clarify what your problem really is? "center"-ing texts usually means `text-align:center` but I assume that's not your desired result?

Comment: Your texts are aligned center, what exact output you need?

Comment: @Abe Caymo: Ah, I understood. I want to do a `text-align:left` in fact. ^^

Comment: @Farhan Ali: I found,. Sorry I wanted to do a `text-align:left`, it's ok now